# words that starts with c but does not sound as k

Tags: spoken-english, letters-of-the-alphabet

The title say it all, i'am looking for all the list of words which starts with `c` but does not sound as `k`, as many know most of the words that starts with `c` usally have a `k` sound in it, e.g cat,clam,carpet,cost...etc.

but `'c'` does not sound as `k`, so are there any words that start with `c` but but does not sound as `k` but as `c`

i tried looking at few sites but they give me explanation of why they sound but not complete list of words

some examples i found are :

```
cis
children
child
```

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: To get a complete list of these words, you can look at a dictionary, where all the words with 'c' are in one place, and write down the words whose pronunciation doesn't start with /k/. Or, with some work, you can do this with computer searches. [Why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700) are you looking for this list? If you tell us what you want to learn from it, we might be able write you an answer that helps with that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples:

Cell as is Cell Phone is pronounced with an 'S' like 'Sell'

Cello the musical instrument has a "ch" sound Ch el o

Ceiling the upper interior surface of a room, pronounced "sealing"